# SSIS DF step failed but output file got created

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have an SSIS package that takes data from SQL table and then has a Multicast step splits the data 20 times.. Then I have 20 Derived columns to create different rows, then union step, then a sort step and finally a flat file destination step. One of the Derived columns steps failed (all the derived column steps are set to fail component) but the package created an output file with just the default header. How can I stop the package creating a flat file even though one of the steps failed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are using a `Flat File Connection Manager` in a `Flat File Destination`, the file is created when the execution starts. This is not related on other package components.But there isn't a stock option to do this you can do some workaround.

**Workarounds**

Just follow one of these links:

- https://munishbansal.wordpress.com/2014/10/22/how-to-prevent-ssis-package-creating-empty-flat-file-at-the-destination/
- https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f824a46b-b504-4644-9ab5-0d1e17ed52b4/prevent-ssis-from-creating-an-empty-flat-file?forum=sqlintegrationservices
- http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/tim_mitchell/2009/09/30/eliminating-empty-output-files-in-ssis/

Comment: Thank you for the reply!

Comment: Thank you for the reply! The issue I will still have is if the package fails I won't get to the step to check e.g row count to delete the file.